# How to add iAd in sprite kit swift 2?

Tags: swift, swift2

I tried using many methods of implementing iAd but non of them are working i want a ad banner in my app in the centre and cotton of the app.

Comment: Post the code of what didn't work.

Comment: i edited it please check it once.

Comment: What's the point when in fact you only have one month and several days to use iAd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iAd network will be discontinued

> The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. Although we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, advertising campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising revenue until June 30. If you’d like to continue promoting your apps through iAd until then, you can create a campaign using iAd Workbench. We will continue to keep you updated, but if you have any questions, contact us.

You should probably be using something else than iAd now.

Comment: Agreed! I would check out Google's AdMob or use Twitter Fabric's MoPub.

Comment: hi please help me with this